# getting number from string

Tags: c#, string, .net-2.0

How I can get number from following string:

```
###E[shouldbesomenumber][space or endofline]
```

[] here only for Illustration not present in the real string.

I am in .net 2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply write a for loop for this simple syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use regular expressions or string operations to isolate *just* the numeric part, and then call `int.Parse`, `int.TryParse`, `decimal.Parse`, `decimal.TryParse` etc depending on the type of number you need to parse.

The regular expression might look something like:

```
@"###E(-?\d+) ?$";
```

You'll need to change it for non-integers, of course. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] arg)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"###E(-?\d+) ?$");        
        string text = "###E123 ";

        Match match = regex.Match(text);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string group = match.Groups[1].Value;
            int parsed = int.Parse(group);
            Console.WriteLine(parsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this could still fail with a number which exceeds the range of `int`. (Another reason to use `int.TryParse`...)

Comment: your Regex not succeeded on "###E97 /M25"

Comment: @NightWalker Perhaps because `###E97 /M25` isn't in the format you asked for? You asked for `###E[shouldbesomenumber][space or endofline]`, but now you are asking for `###E[shouldbesomenumber][space or endofline][other characters]`. The corrected Regex is `"^###E(-?\d+) ?"`

Answer (score 2):

```
static string ExtractNumber(string text)
{
    const string prefix = "###E";
    int index = text.IndexOfAny(new []{' ', '\r', '\n'});
    string number = text.Substring(prefix.Length, index - prefix.Length);
    return number;
}
```

Now that your number is extracted you can parse it or use it as it is.

Comment: You should probably add the check for text.IndexOf('\n').

Comment: @xanatos added it. Though in Windows it is almost always before \n.

Comment: And you could probably make clearer code with [String.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: @xanatos that's not available in .NET 2.0 read the OP's requirement

Comment: `Supported in: 2.0, 1.1, 1.0`

Comment: I'll even add that the code now is better: before it probably returned wrong results with "\r " (\r + space). Now it simply stops at the first "space or similar" character.

Comment: @xanatos no tested the last one. it was indexofany equivalent.

Comment: Bzzzz right and wrong anser :-) Int32.Parse will ignore spaces, but from a string standpoint the result is different: http://ideone.com/EHu2G